# Is Math PSPACE Hard, since we have counterexamples of the belief of efficient proof verification?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity

Kurt Gödel letter to Turing "Only" formulated the problem that, does a polynomial time algorithm exist to answer yes, no question in mathematical statements. Which is considered the source of P vs NP problem, with the "belief" that Verification is poly time ( easy ), and proof is NP ( Hard ). The belief or conjecture of verification being easy is held by almost everyone. I found the following article in Nature Journal : http://www.nature.com/news/the-biggest-mystery-in-mathematics-shinichi-mochizuki-and-the-impenetrable-proof-1.18509

Which stands as a counter example to the belief that proof verification is easy, there are other proofs in finite simple groups not verified for decades. I only shared the one example with authoritative source, to deduce, that while finding proof is hard, verification is also hard, which can be due to introduction of new mathematical objects as in abc conjecture, or due to reductions between different fields, which needs to be verified beyond doubt to be sound. Does this mean, Math is harder than NP, and is infact PSPACE Hard? since both finding and verifying the proof are hard.

Comment: Gödel and Turing deserve Capital Initials.

Comment: In the same vein, finding an article in nature (in a corn field ?) and in Nature is not exactly the same thing... :)

Comment: Sorry for the typing errors. They are legends, and I am in deep awe of their work. reading them, and finding the article, led me to the question.

Comment: Gödel also deserves the dots on the o.

Comment: Under any adequate formalisation of mathematics, finding proofs is undecidable, so much harder than NP hard, PSPACE hard or .... Under the usual formalisations, proof verification is not computationally expensive. The issues exposed in the Nature article you cite are more to do with the sociology of mathematics than with computational complexity and mathematical logic.

Comment: The incompleteness theorem, itself proves that there exist true mathematical statements, that cannot be proved, or in other words, undecidable. My question is on statements, that are provable. example abc conjecture. Under the usual formalism, when we say proof verification is not conputationally expensive, is it assumed that new objects are not invented, like frobenius forms, in IUT theory, and reductions between areas used are always logically sound?

Comment: In order for this question to make any sense, you have to define what your decision problem $Math$ is exactly.